# How to solve $(D^2+4)y=\sin x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

find special solution of $(D^2+4)y=\sin x$

$$y_c=c_1\sin 2x+c_2\cos2x$$

$$y_p=v_1\sin2x+v_2\cos2x$$

$v_1'\sin2x+v_2'\cos2x=0 \tag 1$

$2v_1'\cos2x-2v_2'\sin2x=\sin x\tag 2$

I tried to solve these two equation and found $v_1=-\frac{\cos3x}{12}+\frac{\cos x}{4}$ couldt continue and also answer is given $y=-\frac{x\cos2x}{4}$. it seems my way is wrong or the answer.

and from inverse operator y might be

$$y=\frac{1}{F(-1^2)}\sin x=\frac{1}{3}\sin x$$

Comment: You probably mean $1/(D^2+4)|_{D=i}$ ?

Comment: what are the downvotes for?I'm really curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way is undetermined coefficients: your right side is $\sin(x)$ which is not a solution to the homogeneous equation, so you guess that $y$ is a sinusoid with that frequency, i.e. $y=A \sin(x)+B\cos(x)$. So you get $-A\sin(x)-B\cos(x)+4A\sin(x)+4B\cos(x)=\sin(x)$. Now solve for $A$ and $B$.

I don't see why you're expecting to get a resonant solution (of the form $x$ times a sinusoid). Is it possible your right side was supposed to be $\sin(2x)$? In this case undetermined coefficients with $A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$ breaks, so you introduce some additional factors of $x$ and it works out. Physically this is intuitive: $y''+4y=0$ is a spring with a certain natural frequency, and hitting it with a force of $\sin(2x)$ exactly aligns with this natural frequency. Thus the amplitude should grow.

Comment: $sin2x$ makes sense. because $\frac{1}{D^2+a^2}sinax\cong\frac{-xcosax}{2a}$ . but I didnt know we can use the method of undetermined coefficients in nonlinear equations as you mentioned

Comment: @emmett Your equation doesn't look nonlinear to me: I read it as $y''+4y=\sin(x)$, which is indeed linear. Am I misunderstanding something about your notation?

Comment: I dont really know what this notation states. is this e.g $(D^3+D+4)y= y'''+y'+4y$?

Comment: @emmett That is the usual notation, yes.

Answer (score 1):

The functional analysis approach. This is fairly advanced, and you have to be careful about tricks like this, but I find it amusing.

$$(4+D^2)^{-1} = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{D^{2k}}{4^k}.$$

(This is akin to writing that $\frac{1}{4+x^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{4^k}$.)

But $(-1)^kD^{2k} \sin x = \sin x$.

So:

$$y=(4+D^2)^{-1}\sin x = \frac{1}{4}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^k}\right)\sin x = \frac{1}{3}\sin x$$

Comment: I am reminded of the operator version of Taylor's theorem: "formally" $e^{hD}=\Delta_h$ (where $\Delta_h$ denotes the forward shift). Of course this only provides a non-convergent expansion except in the analytic case, but I still found this both interesting and useful.

Comment: Yes, this trick, for example, only gives us a base answer - the existence of answers to $(4+D^2)y=0$ obviously means that $(4+D^2)^{-1}$ is an abuse of notation.  What it really means is that if the right side is applied to a function, and it converges, then applying $(4+D^2)$ to the result yields the original function. But it doesn't always converge. @Ian

Comment: In particular, if $f(x)=\cos 2x$ then $(-1)^kD^{2k}f(x) = 4^k f(x)$, so the series does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Factor using complex numbers

$$(D+2i)(D-2i)y=(D+2i)z=\sin(x).$$

Then solve twice

$$z=\frac{\sin(x)}{i-2i}+Ce^{2ix}$$
(we have an harmonic response plus the homogeneous response for the Eigenvalue $2i$) and
$$y=\frac{\sin(x)}{(i+2i)(i-2i)}+C'e^{2ix}+C''e^{-2ix}=\frac13\sin(x)+A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x)$$

(two harmonic responses and the homogenous one for the Eigenvalue $-2i$).

Check:

$$y''+4y=-\frac13\sin(x)-4A\cos(2x)-4B\sin(2x)+\frac43\sin(x)+4A\cos(2x)+4B\sin(2x).$$